# Using of nonterminals with same name in rule

Tags: antlr

How can I use as reciever two nonterminals with same name? 
For example, a have this rule:

```
expression returns [int value] : 'min' factor factor { 
    $expression.value = min($factor1.value, $factor2.value) //here
}
```

I need to get value from both factors, but they names are the same. So, if I write `$factor.value` twice, I get value of first factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is solution for your problem:

```
expression returns [int value] : 'min' f1=factor f2=factor { 
    $expression.value = min($f1.value, $f2.value)
}
```